# How to pull a random value from two numbers based on a Mersenne Twister returned value

Tags: python, mersenne-twister

I have implemented a Mersenne Twister in Python using the following [example code](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578056-mersenne-twister/) and while it does work as intended, I am not clear on how to limit results returned to a range of integers. For example, if I wanted to use this mechanism to determine the value of a dice roll, I would (right now, in an incredibly inefficient manner) iterate through potential results from the MT until something falls within the set. There has to be a much more memory-efficient manner to get a value to fall within a set range, like 1-20.

Currently, the algorithm returns a random set of numbers that don't seem to peak anywhere close to the set range:

```
2840889030
2341262508
2626522481
893458501
1134227444
3424236607
4171927007
1414775506
318984778
811882651
1509520423
1796453323
571461449
2606098999
2100002233
202969379
2318195635
1583585513
863717092
1218132929
1044954980
2997947229
867650808
177016714
2532350044
2917724494
2789913671
2793703767
1477382755
2552234519
2230774266
956596469
1165204853
1261233074
1856099289
21274564
1867584221
200970721
2112891842
139474834
93227265
1919721548
1026587194
30693196
3114464709
2194502660
2235520335
1877205724
1093736467
3136329929
1838505684
1358237877
2394536120
1268347552
1222927042
2982839076
1155599683
1943346953
3778719619
1483759762
3227630028
2775862513
2991889829
4252811853
995611629
626323532
3895812866
4027023347
3778533921
3840271846
4289281429
2263887842
402963991
2957069652
238880521
3643974307
472466724
3309455978
3588191581
1390613042
290666747
1375502175
1172854301
2159248842
3279978887
2206149102
804187781
3811948116
4134597627
1556281173
2590972812
3291094915
1836658937
3721612785
365099684
3884686172
2966532828
3609464378
1672431128
3959413372
```

For testing purposes I implemented the current test logic (part of `__main__`) and so far it just runs infinitely.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Based on the pseudocode in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister. Generates uniformly distributed 32-bit integers in the range [0, 232 − 1] with the MT19937 algorithm

Yaşar Arabacı <yasar11732 et gmail nokta com>
"""
# Create a length 624 list to store the state of the generator
MT = [0 for i in xrange(624)]
index = 0

# To get last 32 bits
bitmask_1 = (2 ** 32) - 1

# To get 32. bit
bitmask_2 = 2 ** 31

# To get last 31 bits
bitmask_3 = (2 ** 31) - 1

def initialize_generator(seed):
    "Initialize the generator from a seed"
    global MT
    global bitmask_1
    MT[0] = seed
    for i in xrange(1,624):
        MT[i] = ((1812433253 * MT[i-1]) ^ ((MT[i-1] >> 30) + i)) & bitmask_1


def extract_number():
    """
    Extract a tempered pseudorandom number based on the index-th value,
    calling generate_numbers() every 624 numbers
    """
    global index
    global MT
    if index == 0:
        generate_numbers()
    y = MT[index]
    y ^= y >> 11
    y ^= (y << 7) & 2636928640
    y ^= (y << 15) & 4022730752
    y ^= y >> 18

    index = (index + 1) % 624
    return y

def generate_numbers():
    "Generate an array of 624 untempered numbers"
    global MT
    for i in xrange(624):
        y = (MT[i] & bitmask_2) + (MT[(i + 1 ) % 624] & bitmask_3)
        MT[i] = MT[(i + 397) % 624] ^ (y >> 1)
        if y % 2 != 0:
            MT[i] ^= 2567483615

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    solved = False
    initialize_generator(now.microsecond)
    #for i in xrange(10):
    #    "Print 10 random numbers as an example"
    while(solved != True):
        generated_number = extract_number()
        while(generated_number <= 20 and generated_number >= 1):
            print generated_number
            solved = True
```

Any advice on how to implement? It appears that it may not even get a chance to drop down to a number within the predefined set.

Comment: Please provide sample input, current output, expected output, and your attempts at producing the expected output.

Comment: Can I ask why are you using the code in the link you're referring to while you can simply use python's [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module?

Comment: I am using the implementation above as the actual framework (Godot Engine) i'm implementing the MT algorithm for doesn't use the twister, at least from what i've evaluated in the documentation, its random methods aren't based on MT, and for some functionality, I would prefer to use MT. I will update the question with additional output data, and the for statement shortly.

Comment: There's still the question why you don't use Python's standard random module.  Either directly or at least to look at its (Python) source code to find an answer to your question.